# what does " gbp:error: upstream/1.5.13 is not a valid treeish" mean?

Tags: debian, compiling, git, packaging

I want to build a debian package with git build package.(gbp)
I passed all steps, and at least, when I entered `gbp buildpackage`, This error appeared.

what does it mean?
and what should I do?

```
gbp:error: upstream/1.5.13 is not a valid treeish
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current tag/branch you are in, is not a Debian source tree, it doesn't contain the `debian/` directory in its root. This is evident because you are using a "upstream/" branch, a name utilized to upload the pristine source tree to git repositories. Try using the branch stable, testing or unstable, or any branch that starts with Debian or a commit tagged using the Debian versioning scheme.

Comment: I often use git to create a debian specific branch; `git checkout -b debian/master`

Answer (score 6):

This can be caused by the tarball not being present in the parent directory. I get this (highly crypric) message even with a debian/ folder present.

My solution was to use uscan to get the watch file to download a fresh copy of the tarball

```
uscan --force-download
```

Comment: I get this too. One answer is to ensure that you have spelled the tarball's name correctly according to Debian's requirements and that it has the 'orig' name in it as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to create a tag with version number named like 'upstream/1.5.13' in the git repository to fix this error.